# Vim: changing tabs to spaces

Tags: vim, conversion, text-editing

I know this question has been asked many times, but I'm not finding a solution to my problem in particular, mostly because I can't even really identify the problem.

Here's the timeline of events:

- open old python file (written with python2.7) - everything is fine
- change key bindings to execute .py files with python3 instead of python2.7 - as expected, lot's of `IndentError`s, but file is still the same structure/layout/number of spaces/tabs
- added `expandtab` to my .vimrc - no more `IndentError`s do to inconsistency anymore, but new `IndentError`s all over the place because the structure of my source code is now all out of whack.
- I remove `expandtab` from my .vimrc and I still get the same out of whack source, even if I kill-session, quite iTerm, pull the source fresh from github...WHY!?

Just to be clear, there are only TWO things that have been altered in my vimrc in like the past few months and both alterations were made this morning. The first was remaping `<F9>` to issue a shell command for python3 instead of 2.7, which DID NOT affect the structure of my source code. The second change was adding `expandtab` which messed everything up...removing `expandtab` doesn't return my vim experience to the way it was prior to adding it.

The structural alterations to my source are semi-uniform, so let me try and explain what's actually happening.

What used to look like:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        suite of code
```

now looks like:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
    suite of code
```

and it's like this across the board for what seems like all nested suites of code...in other words, the first expansion of tabs into 4 spaces works fine, but instead of expanding tabs nested further within the first tab, it looks like it just deletes the tab instead.

There are other weird things going on, but I can't really see a pattern.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: It looks like your first indent was four spaces, and your second indent was a tab, with the code being written for a `tabstop` of 8. Vim is either displaying or expanding with the assumption that `tabstop=4`. Do you have the original source from before you edited the files with the bad vim settings?

Comment: Here's the source:

https://github.com/Aweeeezy/Simulator/blob/master/GUI.py

It's not possible that the code was written for a `tabstop=8` because I've had the same .vimrc (with `tabstop=4`) since before I even knew python.

Comment: The code is definitely `tabstop=8`, I can select the single tabs on the 8-space indents. And python in mixed indent mode treats tabs as eight spaces. I don't know how your vim configuration was working to show it before.

Comment: Interesting...I must have added tabstop at sometime in between, though I don't recall it.

Anyways, thanks for isolating the problem. Any advice on retroactively fitting source code as if it was written with `tabstop=4` instead?

edit: or should I just change `tabstop` back to 8?

Comment: `%s/\t/(eight spaces)/g`. You should not have tabs in python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appearance, with every other indent level dropped, is usually (and seems to be the case in your code) a symptom of looking at code which has 4 spaces per indent, but 8-space tabs tabs on every other line (e.g. 4s, 1t, 1t4s, 2t), with a `tabstop` setting of 4.

For Python code, you should simply replace all tabs in the code with eight spaces, since that was how the interpreter was treating it. In general you could deal with situations like this by using the [`:retab`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:retab) command *after* setting `tabstop` to the value the source code was originally written with, so e.g.

```
:set ts=8
:retab 4
```

If `expandtab` is set, retab will replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: Perfect!

Before your edit, I tried `:set tabstop=8` followed by `:retab!` and that did the magic.

Now onto the next issue of trying to merge my packages from my old version of python into the new one :/ I should have heeded the "always install with a virtual env" advice a long time ago. I still don't really understand how that works.